# Importance of '0' character and << operator in this program

Tags: c, char, bit-shift

```
    int getint(void)
    {
        int n=0;
        char c=getchar_unlocked();
        while(c<'0'||c>'9')
            c=getchar_unlocked();
        while(c>='0'&&c<='9')
        {
            n = (n<<3)+(n<<1)+c-'0';   // THE IS THE ALGO
            c=getchar_unlocked();
        }

        return n;
    }
```

The above code is about input the values and return n.
With the formula above the code runs successfully .I also tried to run it with the formula
n=c-'0'  , and it runs without any issues.But when I removed the '0' from the formula,it does not work.
I want to know that if it runs without "<< " additional code ,why it had used in the code...also explain why the character is subtracted by '0'.

Comment: Please in detail explain what you consider "*Successful*"/"*without any issues*" and "*does not work*".

Comment: with successful  I  meant to say that the code works ,the main thing i wanna ask is regarding the formula that is used in the code.

Comment: "Regarding the formula that is used in the code" is not a question. It's not even a sentence.

Comment: `while(c<'0'&&c>'9')` is always false. (maybe you want `||` ?)

Comment: '0' is not a null character, '\0' is

Comment: BTW: now you have changed **both** while() conditions. They should be different (complements) (`while(c>='0'||c<'9')` is always true)

Comment: There is a difference between the Null character `'\0'` also often refered to as "`NUL`", the macro `NULL` and the value of `0`. This question has nothing to do with the Null character `'\0'`.

Answer (score 6):

This expression

```
(n<<3)+(n<<1)
```

is equivalent to

```
8 * n + 2 *n
```

that in turn is equal to

```
10 * n
```

Thus this statement

```
n=(n<<3)+(n<<1)+c-'0';
```

can be rewritten

```
n = 10 * n + c - '0';
```

On the other hand, c - '0' yields the integer digit that corresponds to the digit representation as a character in the variable `c`. For example if the variable `c`  stores character digit '2' then `'2'` - `'0'` yields `2`.

So for example if the following sequence of digits '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' is entered then as a result you will get the number `12345`.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the NUL character (`'\0'`, `0`), that is ASCII zero. `n = c - '0';` converts an ASCII digit into the value of the digit.

```
'0' - '0' = 0
'1' - '0' = 1
'2' - '0' = 2
...
'9' - '0' = 9
```

Comment: ok thanks, and what about the need to put this (n<<3)+(n<<1) in the formula

Comment: "*converts an ASCII ...*" ... not just ASCII encoded "digits"?

Comment: Re "*what about the need to put this (n<<3)+(n<<1) in the formula*", Well, what about it?

Comment: @alk, Re "*not just ASCII encoded "digits"?*", Well, you can subtract `'0'` from any number you want, but that's what's being done here, as imposed by earlier checks in the code.